# How to create method public static boolean setType(Resource resource, String typeName) in jena rdf

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology

```
Can you please help me in building the code in setting a Resource to a Class

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.Individual;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Dataset;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ReadWrite;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory;

public class ModelMain {

    String dbName = "DataBase";
    String ns1 =  "http://text.book/Someone#";
    String ns;
    Dataset ds;
    OntModel m;
```

// created a model and stored in database
        public StoryModel(String Name){

```
        ns = ns1 + Name;
        ds = TDBFactory.createDataset(dbName);
        m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

    }
```

// Assigning resource to class
        public void initModel() {

```
        m.createClass(ns + "Thing");
        m.createClass(ns + "Object");
        saveModel();

    }
```

//read and write model
        public void saveModel() {

```
        ds.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
        m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");

    }
```

// creating a resource
        public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String clsName) {

```
        String resourceuri = ns + resourceName;
        String classuri = ns + className;

        Resource classr = m.getResource(classuri);
        Individual i = m.createIndividual(resourceuri, classr);

        return i;

    }
```

// Assigning type to resource
        public static boolean setType(Resource resource, String typeName) 
        {
            //how to assign type to a resource
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a statement to the data:

```
model.add(resource, RDF.type, TheTypeAsAResource) ;
```

Comment: I am very poor at jena I cant understand how this "model.add(resource, RDF.type, TheTypeAsAResource) ; " works.... Can you please explain.. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have an [OntResource](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html) (which [Individual](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/Individual.html) is), then you may potentially consider use of the [setPropertyValue(Property, RDFNode)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#setPropertyValue%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29) method to set a type. Note that this differs only from [@AndyS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960064/2528639) in that it removes any other `RDF.type` properties that already exist in the graph before adding the new triple.

Starting with the model:

```
:a rdf:type :Cat .
:a rdf:type :DomesticAnimal .
```

The following code (assuming `a` is an `Individual`):

```
a.setPropertyValue(RDF.type, TheTypeAsResource);
```

Will result in the model:

```
a: rdf:type :theType .
```

This, naturally, will only serve your purpose if you do not intend to add an additional type to the resource, and instead, intend to set a specific type for that resource to have.